# "Number of infected rose 25,5%" — Is a noun/pronoun required there?

Tags: word-usage, pronouns, nouns

I'm currently writing an article in English about coverage of the pandemic in Portuguese news. Examples have to be translated, and  most of the time, doubts come from the simplest things. This one had me searching through various grammars, but I found no clear answer.

In Portuguese, there's this headline: "*Número de infectados subiu 25,5%*".
A literal translation would be "Number of infected rose 25,5%".

The translation doesn't *feel* right without a noun ("Number of infected [people] rose 25,5%") or a pronoun ("Number of [those] infected rose 25,5%"). But are these really necessary? Can you point me to a grammar that actually explains this? (It's an academic article, so I need to provide references.)

Comment: You may want to look up **headlinese**.  In writing headlines, we often leave out extraneous words.

Comment: Spelling: **noun**, **pronoun**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Headlines in English are often written in an abbreviated/shortened form of English, which isn't always strictly grammatical. Many words can be missed out if they are obvious from the context.  You should check some English languages newspapers for more examples of this. It's especially common in tabloid newspapers.

If I were to write it, perhaps something like ***Infections rise 25.5%*** or **Number infected rises 25.5%** - both of these are completely acceptable. We will know it's an abbreviated form of "[The] number [of] infected [people] rises [by] 25.5%".

There's no need to mention "people" as it would be obvious from the context of the article. News headlines often also tend to be written in the simple present tense especially if it's a current event. Also, note that in English usage a comma is **never** used as a decimal point. It should be a full stop (aka a period).

Comment: Expats living in Europe with both sterling and euro accounts, become aware that the positions of commas and full stops in the two currencies' statements and invoices are reversed. **£10,000.00  or €10.000,00**

Comment: Thank you. I do read newspapers in english (not tabloids) but "Number of infected" still seemed very crude. I will compare these headlines with those of The Sun, so I think I will get used to it.

Comment: @prodrigues - you don't need to use "of", it's better to omit it here. Use this instead:  **Number infected rises 25.5%** <<--- this is absolutely fine, not "crude" at all.  These kinds of headlines are very common  in English newspapers. We don't expect these to follow formal grammar rules.

Answer (score 2):

It's grammatically possible in English to use an adjective to mean 'people of that description', but only in the plural, unlike some other languages - for instance *the wounded, the poor.* See [this explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalized_adjective). (Please note that **noun** and **pronoun** both end with 'n'.)

However, in recent decades it has been considered more polite to speak of, for example 'disabled people' rather than 'the disabled'.

It's usual, though, to use the minimum of words in a headline, so I think 'Number of infected rose 25.5%' would be considered acceptable.

Comment: +1, though strictly I think that in the most correct circles "disabled" as a word is frowned upon. "Physically challenged" would be preferred - though I still tend to use "disabled".

Comment: @WS2 - I'm not sure where you are from, but in the UK "disabled" is the preferred polite form, and is definitely not frowned upon. This may differ in other English speaking countries of course.

Comment: @BillyKerr - my organisation prefers 'person/people with a disability'.

Comment: @Kate - In relation to polite forms, I think it would be more correct to use "person with a disability" - the person comes first. Thank you for the answer, and for the note on "noun/pronoun", I got it mixed up with Portuguese.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - yeah but that's for organisations, many of which use special terms that aren't used by the general public (far less in newspapers).  I worked in the third sector for many years (a learning disability charity) and I am aware of this usage.

Comment: You are right, prodrigues. I was thinking back to the days when I was a library cataloguer and had to produce subject index entries, but now I come to think of it, 'people with disabilities' was the approved form.

Comment: @BillyKerr Have no doubt about where I'm from - I'm as British as mushy peas or a pint of ale in the Dog & Duck. But though I'd use "disabled", "disabled person" etc. I sense my children would tell me off - they do for most things.

Comment: Not only in the plural - cf. "the deceased", "the accused" etc.

Comment: @prodrigues This is a complicated issue - while "person-first" language is often promoted as being more polite, some disability groups actually prefer identity-first ("blind person", etc. etc.) This is particularly common among blind, deaf, and autistic people.

Comment: @Geoffrey - while I believe person-first laguage makes sense, I think that, as with every other label, "ask first" is the golden rule.

Comment: @prodrigues You won't go wrong with "ask first"! There is a lot of nuance around PFL vs. IFL but SE comments aren't a good medium for it, alas.

Answer (score 2):

First, as Kate Bunting pointed out, headlines are often condensed and so not technically grammatical.

Second, she is correct that it **frequently** is incorrect in English to try to turn a modified noun into a new noun by omitting the noun. If you are talking about red apples, you can say “the apples” or “the red ones,” but not “the reds.”

And, third, she is also correct that there are exceptions to the preceding rule. It is difficult to give an exhaustive list because it is so dependent on context.

In a paragraph about mountains, you can say “the taller are” or “the tallest is” to refer to the taller mountains or the tallest mountain respectively. But it would strange to say “the tall” to mean “the tall mountains.”

Adjectives that dichotomize seem to permit the omission of a noun with fair frequency: “the rich” versus “the poor;” “the sick” and “the healthy.” And so you can say “I like reds” in the context of discussing wines (compare to my previous example of apples).

Because participles can be used as part of verb phrases, as adjectives, and as nouns, it is frequently a matter of opinion how they are best classified in a specific case. Notice that “infected” is the perfect-passive participle of “infect.” Whether a noun has been omitted after an adjectival use of a participle or part of a relative clause has been omitted is not a meaningful debate. “The number infected” can be interpreted as “the number of those who were infected” or as “the number of infected people.”

Notice that this usage in the context of number is not restricted to numbers of people. If we were talking about production of automobiles, “the number made” would be understood as “the number of automobiles that were made.

Answer (score 1):

The headline as translated would be acceptable in English, except that the percentage should be written as 25.5% (change the “,” to “.”).
Headlines are meant to be succinct and do not require all of the elements of a normal sentence.